# Nodejs loops iterating before executing the mysql queries embedded inside them

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

**I am unable to return the projectIds array after the mysql statements have finished executing as the loop is iterating before executing them. This results in empty array being returned everytime.**

```
function fetchProjects (projects, userId, callback) {
  projectIds = [];
    Object.keys(projects).forEach(function(key) {
      var row = projects[key];
      const sql = 'create table if not exists users_' + row.project_id + '(sno int primary key auto_increment, iteration_no int not null, user_id int not null, foreign key(iteration_no) references pro_' + row.project_id + '(iteration_no), foreign key(user_id) references user(user_id))';
      connection.query(sql, function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err.sqlMessage);
          return callback(err.sqlMessage, false);
        } else {
          // console.log("First statement executed");
          const sql1 = "select distinct t1.project_id, t1.project_name, t1.client, t1.initial_department_id, t1.start_date, t1.status, t1.current_department, t1.currently_assigned_user from project t1, users_" + row.project_id + " t2 where t1.project_id = '" + row.project_id + "' and (select user_id from users_" + row.project_id +" where user_id = " + userId + ")";
          connection.query(sql1, function(err, result1) {
            if(err) {
              console.log(err.sqlMessage);
              return callback(err.sqlMessage, false);
            } else {
              if(result1.length > 0) {
                console.log(result1);
                projectIds.push(result1);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      });
      // console.log("Iterating");
    });
    return callback(false, projectIds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to execute callback style code in `forEach` which doesn't wait for the query to finish. That is the reason you are getting emoty array. I would make few modifications

- Use promise version of the `query` method. Check the documentation of mysql node package
- Use `for..of` loop instead of forEach.
- Make the function `async`
- Also `await` when you call the promise version of query method.

Hope this helps.